# Heroku remote MongoDB connect with php

Tags: php, mongodb, heroku

Im getting error while connecting to remote mongoDb from Heroku facebook app

```
Class 'Mongo' not found
```

I guess mongo driver isnt supported out of box? How can i install it on heroku?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to install mongo extension to your app

> Vendor the Mongo driver with your application. You can download it
>   here:
>
> https://github.com/wuputah/heroku-libraries/raw/master/php/mongo/mongo.so
>   Add it to a folder like "ext".
>
> Add a php.ini file to the root of your application:
>
> extension_dir = "/app/www/ext/" extension=mongo.so

found solution here:
https://gist.github.com/1288447